# Where should I put my user page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, coding-style

This is just a stylistic questions I wanted some opinions on. I'm working a RoR app that has two models, Posts and Users. The posts can be viewed individually or as lists via the post_controller, and all posts have a user. Now, I want to implement a user page that lists all posts from a specific user. Obviously, that page will need its own view, but should I put the control for it in the Post Controller or the User Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create another controller. The best option would be to utilize nested resources like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

That way, the path /users/:user_id/posts will be created which would correspond to your index action in the Post controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing would be creating a new controller

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this in your User controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts
end
```

Comment: Because there is an easier, cleaner way of doing it. See @amb110395's answer.